# Get rid of stylecop.json from nuget package

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package, stylecop, roslyn-code-analysis

I've setup building nuget package from my project using package tab in project options. Everything seems to work except that my nuget package contains stylecop.json file. Build action for this file is set to "C# analyzer additional file". How to get rid of this file from nuget package?

This is my csproj file content

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageLicenseUrl>https://github.com/aixasz/ImageShareTemplate/blob/develop/LICENSE</PackageLicenseUrl>
    <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/aixasz/ImageShareTemplate/</PackageProjectUrl>
    <Description>ImageShareTemplate is image template library to share an image to social like facebook, twitter, etc.</Description>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/aixasz/ImageShareTemplate/</RepositoryUrl>
    <PackageTags>image socialmedia</PackageTags>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="1.0.0-beta0001" />
    <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing" Version="1.0.0-beta0001" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Fonts\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: How are you generating your nuget package?  You can specify excludes in the nuspec file.

Comment: There is no nuspec file. The whole configuration is in csproj file.

Comment: Is this a .net standard / core project? (sdk-based)

Comment: @MartinUllrich yes, that's right

Comment: can you share your csproj file? at least the item definitions containing `stylecop.json`? (just because these additional files aren't packed by default)

Comment: @MartinUllrich I've updated my question